# How to fix this.uuid is not a function discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Hello actually I wanted to make minecraft playerinfo command but I wanted it and I got it on github it was a bit old but I tried to convert it to discord.js v14 code. But I got this error.

```
TypeError: this.getUuid is not a function
```

Can you help me please heres the original code: https://github.com/Jystro/Minecraft-info-bot/blob/master/commands/player.js

```js
const mojang = require('mojang-api');
const https = require('https');
const {
    EmbedBuilder
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'playerinfo',
    description: 'Diplays player\'s name, uuid, skin, cape and name history',
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    
        //check that a value is sent
        if(!args.length) {
            message.reply('please specify the player\'s uuid');
            return;
        }
        let uuid = args[0]
        //get uuid
        this.getUuid(args[0], (err, uuid) => {
          if(err) {
                message.channel.send('An error occurred. This might be because the player does not exist');
                return;
            }
            //check that uuid exists
            mojang.profile(uuid, (err, resp) => {
                if(err) {
                    message.reply('that player\'s uuid does not exist');
                    return;
                }
                //get name history
                mojang.nameHistory(uuid, (err, resp1) => {
                    if(err) {
                        message.reply('there was an error trying to retrieve the data');
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    let nameHistory = [];
                    resp1.forEach(element => {
                        nameHistory.push(element.name);
                    });
                    nameHistory = nameHistory.join(', ');
                    //create embed message
                    const embedMessage = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setColor('Random')
                        .setTitle(resp.name)
                        .setDescription(resp.name + "'s profile")
                        .setThumbnail('https://crafatar.com/avatars/' + resp.id + '.png?overlay')
                        .addFields(
                          {
                            name: 'Name',
                            value: resp.name
                          },
                          {
                            name: 'UUID',
                            value: resp.id
                          },
                          {
                            name: 'Skin',
                            value: 'https://crafatar.com/skins/' + resp.id + '.png'
                          })
                        .setImage('https://crafatar.com/renders/body/' + resp.id + '.png?overlay')
                        
                    //check if cape exists
                    let cape = 'https://crafatar.com/capes/' + resp.id + '.png';
                    const req = https.request(cape, res => {
                        if(res.statusCode == 200) {
                            embedMessage.fields.push({ name: 'Cape', value: cape });
                        }
                        embedMessage.fields.push({ name: 'Name history', value: nameHistory });
                        //send embed
                        message.channel.send({  embed: embedMessage  });
                    });
                    req.on('error', err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        message.reply('there was an error while retrieving the cape');
                    })
                    req.end();
                });
            });
        })
        
    },
    //function to get uuid from uuid/name
    getUuid(value, cb) {
        let error = false;
        let regex = /^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i //regex for uuids
        if(!value.match(regex)) {
            mojang.nameToUuid(value, (err, resp) => {
                if(err || !resp.length) {
                    error = true;
                    cb(error, null);
                    return;
                }
                cb(error, resp[0].id);
            });
        }
        else { cb(error, value); }
    }
                                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your usage of the `this` keyword and arrow functions.

The main takeaway is this:

**Arrow functions don't redeclare this, while anonymous functions do.**

This means that when you call the `run()` method somewhere else in the code, the `this` keyword in the `run` method will refer to whatever `this` is in the current context of where it was executed, which isn't what you want.

To redeclare `this` to your object, you should rewrite your arrow function as an anonymous function.

```js
module.exports = {
  run: async function(client, message, args) {
    // you can now safely use `this` in this method
  }
}
```